# Can my iOS published app, targeted for ios 7 built in xcode 5, run in ios 10.2 devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am creating an app via Cordova. The build is complete in android ,and now I am creating an app for iOS.

I am running OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and the max version XCODE is 5.1. The maximum version of iOS SDK that Xcode 5 supports iOS 7 SDK.

So I need to know before hand whether my app targeting iOS 7 will run on the latest devices ?

Forgive me if my question is a bit naive. I am new to iOS/ mac environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to update the Xcode to the lasted version(`8.2.1`), and you can test your app in Xcode, with the simulotar `10.2`(if you update the Xcode the lasted version, simulator will also have the lasted os version).

I am not mean this is test your cordova app if can run in device with `10.2` version, this step is test your cordova app if is operation normally in `10.2` version, if it will have some issues in this version, this is necessary.